# Deploying an angular node app, with aws ec2 - Error: Could not connect to the server

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, deployment

I'm trying to deploy an angular/node app in aws ec2, but I'm having this error, that I cannot solve.

[image]

My app was built using `ng build --prod`

I have this file structure

[image]

I'm calling node this way:

```
...
const AUTH_API = 'http://localhost:8080/api/authPsi/';
...

 login(credentials): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(AUTH_API + 'signin', {
      email: credentials.email,
      password: credentials.password
    }, httpOptions);
  }
...
```

I've tried with the server IP also.

In the server.js I have this cors policy

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const dbConfig = require("./db.config");

const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:4200"
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
   listen         80 default_server;
   listen         [::]:80 default_server;
   server_name    localhost;
   root           /dist/psiquests;
location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

I believe I've putted everything I need to explain, but let me know if you need more information.

I believe it's a cors problem but don' know how to resolve.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you have localhost url's being called in the browser. When this happens, your computer will resolve the request to it's own localhost. If you want to deploy this to a server you will need to use same url for the service as you are using to access the page.

For example, if your page is loaded from [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) then your `AUTH_API` variable looks like it should be [www.domain.com/your_auth_path](http://www.domain.com/your_auth_path).

Edit: I see you say you've tried with the server IP as well. It would be more helpful if you posted all the examples. If it's not the localhost resolution then it could be COR's being incorrectly configured.

If your backend and frontend are both served from the same domain and subdomain you should not need to have COR's enabled.

A good way to rule out whether or not it's a COR's error could be to retry the request in Postman. If the request is successful there then it is 99% the COR's issue.

Comment: Should I make a post to http://localhost:8080/api/authPsi/ for example?

Comment: it gives me 200 OK, a get request to it. but still can't figure it out how to set up cors.

Comment: When you access the web page, I assume that you are using something like `https://{your_ec2_instance_ip_address}`. It would appear that your backend should be available on the same address. I'd really need to see more information about what you're deploying. Is your code available somewhere or are you following some kind of guide I can reference?

Answer (score 0):

It was solved using:

```
...
const AUTH_API = '/api/authPsi/';
...

 login(credentials): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(AUTH_API + 'signin', {
      email: credentials.email,
      password: credentials.password
    }, httpOptions);
  }
...
```

and this configuration file for nginx

```
    server {
      charset utf-8;
      listen 80 default_server;
      server_name _;
    
    location / {
           root  dist/folder;
           try_files $uri /index.html;
       }
    
    location /api/{
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
    }
```